# Segmenting order data into new rows based on max quantity pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to generate a new dataframe that takes a certain **total** order and splitting it into actually shippable orders. Max eligibility shows what the maximum number of pallets can be put on an order. So in the below example, a total pallet order of 50, with a max eligibility 24, then I'd like the new dataframe to show the three orders as separate rows with 24, 24 and 2 (adds up to 50).

[image: example]

Code for the example dataframe:

```
df_input = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2021-12-01','2021-12-01','2021-12-02','2021-12-02'],
                    'shipper_id':['S1', 'S2','S1', 'S2'],
                    'pallets':[50, 25, 75, 15],
                    'max_eligability':[24, 14, 24, 14]
                     })
```

My first idea was to create a function that could repeat the full orders into one cell and then add the extra pallets in the end. Then explode the data using pandas .explode function.

```
def planned_routes(df):

df['full_orders'] = df['pallets'] // df['max_eligibility'] # get the total amount of full vans/orders
df['extra_pallets'] = df['pallets'] % df['max_eligibility']
df['order_splits'] = df['max_eligibility'].repeat(df['full_orders']), df['extra_pallets']

df = df.explode('order_splits')
df.drop(['pallets', 'max_eligibility','full_orders','extra_pallets'], axis=1, inplace=True)

return df
```

This approach gives errors in terms of indexing, which I speculate is because I'm trying to explode it without an corresponding index. I'm unsure how to solve this error.

**Is there a more efficient solution to this rather than exploding the dataframe? Like a lambda function I'm missing to be able to generate new rows?**

/ Olle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply a function f to construct the data of a new dataframe:

```
def f(x):
    q = x.pallets // x.max_eligability
    r = x.pallets % x.max_eligability
    l = [x.max_eligability] * q + [r] * (1 if r else 0)
    l = [(x.date, x.shipper_id, v, x.max_eligability) for v in l]
    return l

df_output = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_input.columns,
        data=[j for i in df_input.apply(f, axis=1) for j in i])
```

Output:

```
          date shipper_id  pallets  max_eligability
0   2021-12-01         S1       24               24
1   2021-12-01         S1       24               24
2   2021-12-01         S1        2               24
3   2021-12-01         S2       14               14
4   2021-12-01         S2       11               14
5   2021-12-02         S1       24               24
6   2021-12-02         S1       24               24
7   2021-12-02         S1       24               24
8   2021-12-02         S1        3               24
9   2021-12-02         S2       14               14
10  2021-12-02         S2        1               14
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define a function that turns a given pair of total order size and maximum unit size values into a list of the individual sizes. Then apply that function to the two relevant columns to create a column of those lists. Finally, explode the dataframe on that list column:

```py
def list_loads(value_pair):
    total, max_size = value_pair[0], value_pair[1]
    n_full, remainder = divmod(total, max_size)
    result = n_full * [max_size]
    if remainder > 0:
        result.append(remainder)
    return result

df = df_input[['date', 'shipper_id']].copy()
df['Load'] = df_input[['pallets', 'max_eligability']].apply(list_loads, axis=1)
df = df.explode('Load').reset_index(drop=True)

df
```

```
    date        shipper_id  Load
0   2021-12-01  S1          24
1   2021-12-01  S1          24
2   2021-12-01  S1           2
3   2021-12-01  S2          14
4   2021-12-01  S2          11
5   2021-12-02  S1          24
6   2021-12-02  S1          24
7   2021-12-02  S1          24
8   2021-12-02  S1           3
9   2021-12-02  S2          14
10  2021-12-02  S2           1
```